# Problem with Dash WSGI file after Python 3.8 upgrade on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, wsgi, plotly-dash, pythonanywhere

After upgrading my virtualenv(as recommended using `requirements.txt`), confirming it is *Python 3.8*, reloading the Web Application (ensuring the *PythonAnywhere* Web page is *Python 3.8*) I get the following error.

I note this error has occurred in earlier version of Python 3.8 [Problem Solution](https://bugs.python.org/issue35894).  The answer was to '*pass an empty list as the second argument to Module()*'.  I cannot see how I can do this within the WSGI file. The offending line of code is `from EF16 import EF`. Any thoughts?

```
2020-02-03 05:01:39,514: Error running WSGI application
2020-02-03 05:01:39,523: TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module
2020-02-03 05:01:39,524:   File "/var/www/davidcolinbryant_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 34, in <module>
2020-02-03 05:01:39,524:     from EF16 import EF  # noqa
2020-02-03 05:01:39,524: 
2020-02-03 05:01:39,524:   File "./EF16.py", line 378, in <module>
2020-02-03 05:01:39,525:     EF = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,
2020-02-03 05:01:39,525: 
2020-02-03 05:01:39,525:   File "/home/DavidColinBryant/.virtualenvs/Dash/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 253, in __init__
2020-02-03 05:01:39,525:     self.server = flask.Flask(name) if server else None
2020-02-03 05:01:39,526: 
2020-02-03 05:01:39,526:   File "/home/DavidColinBryant/.virtualenvs/Dash/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 559, in __init__
2020-02-03 05:01:39,526:     self.add_url_rule(
2020-02-03 05:01:39,526: 
2020-02-03 05:01:39,527:   File "/home/DavidColinBryant/.virtualenvs/Dash/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 67, in wrapper_func
2020-02-03 05:01:39,527:     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
2020-02-03 05:01:39,527: 
2020-02-03 05:01:39,527:   File "/home/DavidColinBryant/.virtualenvs/Dash/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1217, in add_url_rule
2020-02-03 05:01:39,527:     self.url_map.add(rule)
2020-02-03 05:01:39,527: 
2020-02-03 05:01:39,528:   File "/home/DavidColinBryant/.virtualenvs/Dash/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1388, in add
2020-02-03 05:01:39,528:     rule.bind(self)
2020-02-03 05:01:39,528: 
2020-02-03 05:01:39,528:   File "/home/DavidColinBryant/.virtualenvs/Dash/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 730, in bind
2020-02-03 05:01:39,528:     self.compile()
2020-02-03 05:01:39,529: 
2020-02-03 05:01:39,529:   File "/home/DavidColinBryant/.virtualenvs/Dash/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 794, in compile
2020-02-03 05:01:39,529:     self._build = self._compile_builder(False).__get__(self, None)
2020-02-03 05:01:39,529: 
2020-02-03 05:01:39,529:   File "/home/DavidColinBryant/.virtualenvs/Dash/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 951, in _compile_builder
2020-02-03 05:01:39,529:     code = compile(module, "<werkzeug routing>", "exec")
```

Comment: On [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/dash/), Dash doesn't list Python 3.8 as a supported version yet; might that be the problem?

Comment: Giles, I think you may be right. It is amazing what a fresh set of eyes does.